# How to iterate through an Json array with same keys, but different values using Faster xml

Tags: java, json, rest, api, fasterxml

1. I am trying to parse the `json` array with same key value which looks something like:

```
Back End Response:"Countries":[{"state":"Queens Land "state":"Tasmania"}].
```

2.I have created classes to read back end response and mapping the values with `faster XML`, but only the last value in the array is getting copied, instead of entire array. This is how I created my `Data Transfer Object` classes.

Now the Test object contains `Countries` array, but only one of the `State` value is read. i.e

```
"Countries":["States":"Tasmania"].
```

Please excuse me for typos. can some one help, can some one suggest whats wrong with the bellow code..

```
private Class Test{
  List<Countries> countries;
}

private class Countries{        
  private String States;
}

private class Mapper {

}
```

In my Mapper class reading the value using faster XML

Comment: Countries should have a `private List<String> States` rather

Comment: There are many issues with this question. First, your `json` is not a valid one, maybe is: `{ "Countries":[{"state":"Queens Land", "state":"Tasmania"}] }`. Also if you want `States` store multiple values, it should be a list as @bradm6s suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your `JSON` payload is:

```
{
  "Countries": [
    {
      "state": "Queens Land",
      "state": "Tasmania"
    }
  ]
}
```

According to [RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6):

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a
> string.  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name
> from the value.  A single comma separates a value from a following
> name. **The names within an object SHOULD be unique**.

In your example, you have not unique names and most `JSON` parsers would skip repeated values and would take only one. So, if you can change backend response, just change it to:

```
{
  "Countries": [
    {
      "state": "Queens Land"
    },
    {
      "state": "Tasmania"
    }
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "Countries": [
    "Queens Land",
    "Tasmania"
  ]
}
```

But if you can not do that, you need to use [Streaming API](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api) and implement your custom deserialiser. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Test test = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Test.class);
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}

class CountriesJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Countries> {

    @Override
    public Countries deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        List<String> states = new ArrayList<>();
        while (p.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (p.currentToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                if ("state".equalsIgnoreCase(p.getText())) {
                    p.nextToken();
                    states.add(p.getText());
                }
            }
        }

        Countries countries = new Countries();
        countries.setStates(states);
        return countries;
    }
}

class Test {

    @JsonProperty("Countries")
    private List<Countries> countries;

    public List<Countries> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public void setCountries(List<Countries> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{" +
                "countries=" + countries +
                '}';
    }
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = CountriesJsonDeserializer.class)
class Countries {
    private List<String> states;

    public List<String> getStates() {
        return states;
    }

    public void setStates(List<String> states) {
        this.states = states;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Countries{" +
                "states=" + states +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above example prints:

```
Test{countries=[Countries{states=[Queens Land, Tasmania]}]}
```

See also:

- [Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)